# What is a two-hot decoder?

Tags: digital-logic, decoder

I am currently learning digital logic and the textbook that I am using briefly mentions about two-hot decoders. I understand how a one-hot decoder works, and the textbook gives an example of a 4 to 16 decoder. However, how would something like a 4 to 5 two-hot decoder work? What do each of the 5 bits represent in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect the decoder to give you five outputs, two of which are on. A possible table:

```
I1 I2 I3 I4   O1 O2 O3 O4 O5
 0  0  0  0    1  1  0  0  0
 0  0  0  1    1  0  1  0  0
 0  0  1  0    0  1  1  0  0
 0  0  1  1    1  0  0  1  0
 0  1  0  0    0  1  0  1  0
 0  1  0  1    0  0  1  1  0
 0  1  1  0    1  0  0  0  1
 0  1  1  1    0  1  0  0  1
 1  0  0  0    0  0  1  0  1
 1  0  0  1    0  0  0  1  1
```

As you see, there are a few undefined states, because there are only \$\binom{2}{5} = 10\$ combinations with exactly two outputs active.

Another possible implementation could be:

```
I1 I2 I3 I4   O1 O2 O3 O4 O5
 0  0  0  1    0  0  0  1  1
 0  0  1  0    0  0  1  0  1
 0  0  1  1    0  0  1  1  0
 0  1  0  0    0  1  0  0  1
 0  1  0  1    0  1  0  1  0
 0  1  1  0    0  1  1  0  0
 1  0  0  0    1  0  0  0  1
 1  0  0  1    1  0  0  1  0
 1  0  1  0    1  0  1  0  0
 1  1  0  0    1  1  0  0  0
```

Here, the outputs 1-4 are taken directly from the inputs, and the fifth output is active exactly when only one of the others is.

There is usually little incentive for building a 4-to-5 two-hot decoder, because you only save one bit, so this is reserved for very special corner cases where you are short one I/O pin somewhere and cannot multiplex others either.